# php read txt file from 5th letter to 6th letter

Tags: php, fread

I'd like to read letters from txt file, but only from 5th to 6th (2 letters)

```
<?  $myFile = "administrator/data.txt"; 
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r'); 
    $theData = fread($fh, 4); 
    fclose($fh); 
?>
```

This code reads the first 4 numbers, but I don't know how to choose letters from 5th to 6th letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [fseek](http://php.net/fseek) to advance the file pointer to the desired position first.

```
...
fseek($fh, 5);
$theData = fread($fh, 2);
...
```